# internal/commonmodels: malformed module path "internal/commonmodels": missing dot in first path element

Tags: go

I am using go version 1.19. My directory structure is as follows:

```
bdmodules
  --awsutils
    --go.mod //content of the go.mod is
       replace bdmodules/commonapiutils => ../../bdmodules/commonapiutils
  --commonapiutils
    --go.mod  //content of the go.mod is
      replace bdmodules/commonmodels => ../../bdmodules/commonmodels
  --commonmodels
    --go.mod //content of the go.mod has entries for external packages
  --gcputils
    --go.mod //content of the go.mod is
       replace bdmodules/commonapiutils => ../../bdmodules/commonapiutils
```

Now, when I run "go mod tidy" on gcputils, commonmodels, commonapiutils there are no errors. But, when I run "go mod tidy" on awsutils it gives me an error:

```
  bdmodules/awsutils imports
        bdmodules/commonapiutils imports
        bdmodules/commonmodels: malformed module path "bdmodules/commonmodels": missing dot in first path element
```

Comment: Do not name module intern, test main or anything other what obviousely will lead to problems.

Comment: @Volker Thanks for your response. Ok, I changed "internal" to "bdmodules" and I am getting the same error. I updated the question to reflect the changes

Comment: Well, just use a sensible name as recommended in the official tutorial (hoping you took that, if not: do it now). And: the error is pretty clear: Add a dot. Try `bdmodules.mycompany` maybe replacing mycompany with your company name.

Comment: And one more: Stop that replacing business and put all into one module: They will have the same lifecycle.

Comment: @Volker Yes, I saw the restrictions on "internal" packages here: https://docs.google.com/document/d/1e8kOo3r51b2BWtTs_1uADIA5djfXhPT36s6eHVRIvaU/edit?usp=sharing
I have looked at this: https://go.dev/blog/package-names. That does not tell me about package name restrictions. Please share any other link if available. If only Go compilers provide better errors... :)
We do not want to put all the code in one module. Although it is convenient, it is harder to manage.

Comment: https://go.dev/doc/, the Tutorials. "Although it is convenient, it is harder to manage." No?